# Rabbitmq - Connecting to cluster from C#

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

We have created a RabbitMQ cluster with two nodes (rabbit and rabbit1). We have 4 queues which are configured to be highly available queues by following http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html and http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html

Before clustering, we used to connect to the node using the snippet below.

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory(){ HostName = _rabbitMQ_Hostname, UserName = _rabbitMQ_Username, Password = _rabbitMQ_Password};
            
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
{
    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: _autoCancellationPNS_QueueName,
    durable: true,
    exclusive: false,
    autoDelete: false,
    arguments: null);

    string message = appointmentId.ToString();
    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    IBasicProperties properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
    properties.DeliveryMode = 2;
    channel.BasicPublish(exchange: _rabbitMQ_Exchange,
        routingKey: _autoCancellationPNS_RoutingKey,
        basicProperties: properties,
        body: body);
    returnMessage.ShortMessage = "Added to queue";
    returnMessage.LongMessage = "Added to queue";
    logger.Debug("|Added to queue");
}
```

How should we deal with cluster?

Answer (score 6):

The `RabbitMQ.Client` have been supporting connecting to multiple hosts for over a year. It was fixed in [pull request #92](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/pull/92). You should be able to do something like the following

```
using (var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection(hostList))
using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
{

}
```

However, with this approach you would need to perform all the recovery etc. yourself. About a year ago, we had massive problem with stability in the `EasyNetQ` client, but since we started using [`RawRabbit`](https://github.com/pardahlman/RawRabbit) our clustered environment and never really had a problem with it.

*Disclaimer: I am the creator of RawRabbit.*

Comment: Please disclose if you made a library you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to the node you prefer.

Exchanges and queues are visible across the cluster.

Using a load-balancer in front of the nodes is common practice, so the clients have to know only the balancer IP/DNS.

```
clients ----> balancer -----> RabbitMQ cluster
```

Answer (score 0):

The .Net client does (to my knowledge) not offer any support for this. You build something yourself to select and connect to a node on the cluster.

For example, if you want to implement a round-robin strategy, the pseudo code would be something like

```
Get list of hostname/port combinations that form the cluster
do {
    try {
        connect to next hostname in the list
    } catch (rabbit connection failed) {
        maybe log a warning
    }
} while not connected
```

Of course you now need to think about connection strategies, retries, number of connection attempts, exponential backoff, ...

... which is why I would strongly recommend to look for a library that already provides this kind of functionality (and much more). One such library is `EasyNetQ` (available on nuget), maybe NServiceBus (with RabbitMq Transport) or MassTransit could also be interesting.

Another approach could be to set up an intelligent loadbalancer in front of the individual nodes (so myrabbitcluster.mycompany.com load balances between the cluster nodes and should then be responsible to detect node failures and take faulty nodes out of the cluster).